# Passing arguments as strings to a function in a shell script

Tags: function, shell, ksh

Calling a function in another script to delete old files - need to pass $1 as string, and not the eval of that arg (filelist from directory)

Have tried:
 - single and double quotes around echo $1 ("$1", '$1')
 - single and double quotes around arg ("/tmp/AB*", '/tmp/AB*')

Have read 3 similar questions here, but unsuccessful at understanding the issue...

AIX 6

```
#!/bin/ksh
#### common load function ######
. /tmp/functions.sh

deletefiles /usr/tmp/AB* 1

#!/bin/sh
# Deletes files from a filelist that are older than X days

deletefiles()  {

echo $1
echo $2

#filelist=$1
#days=$2

#execute
#`find ${filelist} -type f -mtime +${days} -exec rm {} + 2>&1`

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? All arguments are passed as strings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to pass `/usr/tmp/AB*` as is, without expanding it. This can be done with `'/usr/tmp/AB*'`, `"/usr/tmp/AB*"`, or `/usr/tmp/AB\*`.

Then, to confirm that you got the right value, you need to use `"$1"` to prevent wildcard expansion in `echo`:

```
deletefiles() {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$2"
}

deletefiles '/usr/tmp/AB*' 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main problem is that you want AB* expanded in deletefiles().
When you don't do something special, how do you find the last parameter?

You can expand the wildcard within deletefiles() with eval, but eval can do more than you wanted. Another method is swithing the order of your parameters (days first) end use `shift` for deleting days from the paramaterlist when you assigned it to a var.

I'll show both solutions.

```
deletefiles_notsecure()  {
        filelist="$(eval echo $1)"
        days=$2
        echo "Filelist: $filelist"
        echo "Days: $days"
}

deletefiles_secure()  {
        days=$1
        shift
        filelist="$*"
        echo "Filelist: $filelist"
        echo "Days: $days"
}

# deletefiles /usr/tmp/AB* 1
deletefiles_notsecure "/tmp/*" 1
echo ===========
deletefiles_secure 1 /tmp/*
```

As you can see, the second form can be used without quotes from the caller, so that will be easier to use.
Note: It will expand the vars during the call, relative to path you are standing in. When deletefiles_secure() starts with `cd "${logdir}"` and you are standing in your $HOME when you call `deletefiles_secure 1 access*.log*` an access.log in your homedir will be found. Use full paths on your local computer!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use *eval* if you can avoid it: *find* does have a *-name* option to specify a file-mask, eg:

```
deletefiles () {
    find "$1" -name "$2" ...
}

deletefiles /somedir 'AB*'
```